# Trying to get source of a webpage using get in perl

Tags: perl, get, html

I'm trying to get source of a webpage in my perl code, basically this website is a local server and the link is http://gold.star.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LASTESTDMS/  I'm able to ping the server, but the get command in my code doesn't seem to be getting the page source  here is the code I'm trying with

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::Simple;
my $dmsurl = 'http://gold.star.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTDMS/'; 
my $page = get($dmsurl) or die "cannot\n";
print $page;
```

Every-times I run this code I get the message "Cannot"    but the same link when I try with my browser in opens , but in code its not working.

Comment: Do you get page with `curl` or `wget`? I mean, your code works fine for me with some other URL.

Comment: yes.. It works fine with some other URLs but not with this one, also the above link works fine with web browsers. And gold.star.com is a internal server in our network.

Comment: What does the server error and access logs tell you about the access?

Comment: Does your network use a proxy?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296653/get-not-working-in-perl#6296843

Answer (score 5):

It's possible your site is blocking your script because it thinks its a bot.  You want to find out by looking at the status code LWP is getting from your site.  Unfortunately, you can't do that with `get`.  You can with `getprint` and `getstore`.

```
use LWP::Simple;
my $dmsurl = 'http://gold.star.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTDMS/'; 
my $rc = getprint($dmsurl);
print status_message($rc);
```

`getprint` will display the status code if it fails, so printing the status message is a bit redundant.  For more on `$rc`, see [HTTP::Status](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?HTTP%3a%3aStatus).

Answer (score 3):

The target site may check User-Agent field and response with 404 HTTP error for example.

I'll recommend you to set User-Agent (using WWW::Mechanize):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use WWW::Mechanize;
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.18) Gecko/20110614 Firefox/3.6.18" );
my $dmsurl = 'http://gold.star.com/isos/preFCS5.4/LATESTDMS/'; 
$mech->get($dmsurl);
print $mech->content();
```